Value of type '[ListB]' has no member 'books' error
I'm getting an error "Value of type '[ListB]' has no member 'books'" from func below on line "books = hardfictList.books" below
func fetchAPIDataTop100FHC() {
        
        let url = myUrl
              AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil, interceptor: nil)
                .response{ resp in
                    switch resp.result{
                    case .success(let data):
                        do{
                            let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(NYTTop100FictionModel.self, from: data!)
                             let hardfictList = jsonData.results.listsb.filter ({ $0.listNameEncoded == "hardcover-fiction" })
                            //print(jsonData.results.listsb)
                            books = hardfictList.books
                        } catch {
                            print(String(describing: error))
                        }
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(String(describing: error))
                    }
                } //end response

        } //end fetch API

Code for struct ListB and Book below
struct Result: Decodable {
  let bestsellersDate: String
  let publishedDate: String
  let publishedDateDescription: String
  let previousPublishedDate: String
  let nextPublishedDate: String
  let listsb: [ListB]

  private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case bestsellersDate = "bestsellers_date"
    case publishedDate = "published_date"
    case publishedDateDescription = "published_date_description"
    case previousPublishedDate = "previous_published_date"
    case nextPublishedDate = "next_published_date"
    case listsb = "lists"
  }

  init(bestsellersDate: String, publishedDate: String, publishedDateDescription: String, previousPublishedDate: String, nextPublishedDate: String, listsb: [ListB]) {
    self.bestsellersDate = bestsellersDate
    self.publishedDate = publishedDate
    self.publishedDateDescription = publishedDateDescription
    self.previousPublishedDate = previousPublishedDate
    self.nextPublishedDate = nextPublishedDate
    self.listsb = listsb
  }
}

struct ListB: Decodable {
//struct ListB: Codable {
  let listID: Int
  let listName: String
  let listNameEncoded: String
  let displayName: String
  let updated: String
  //let listImage: Any?
  //let listImageWidth: Any?
  //let listImageHeight: Any?
  let books: [Book]

  private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case listID = "list_id"
    case listName = "list_name"
    case listNameEncoded = "list_name_encoded"
    case displayName = "display_name"
    case updated
    //case listImage = "list_image"
    //case listImageWidth = "list_image_width"
    //case listImageHeight = "list_image_height"
    case books
  }

    init(listID: Int, listName: String, listNameEncoded: String, displayName: String, updated: String, books: [Book]) {
  //init(listID: Int, listName: String, listNameEncoded: String, displayName: String, updated: String, listImage: Any?, listImageWidth: Any?, listImageHeight: Any?, books: [Book]) {
    self.listID = listID
    self.listName = listName
    self.listNameEncoded = listNameEncoded
    self.displayName = displayName
    self.updated = updated
    //self.listImage = listImage
    //self.listImageWidth = listImageWidth
    //self.listImageHeight = listImageHeight
    self.books = books
  }
}

struct Book: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
  let ageGroup: String
  let amazonProductURL: URL
  let articleChapterLink: String
  let author: String
  let bookImage: URL?
  let bookImageWidth: Int?
  let bookImageHeight: Int?
  let bookReviewLink: String
  let bookUri: URL
  let btrn: String
  let contributor: String
  let contributorNote: String
  let createdDate: String
  let description: String
  let firstChapterLink: String
  let price: String
  let primaryIsbn10: String
  let primaryIsbn13: String
  let publisher: String
  let rank: Int
  let rankLastWeek: Int
  let sundayReviewLink: String
  let title: String
  let updatedDate: String
  let weeksOnList: Int
  let buyLinks: [BuyLink]

  private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case ageGroup = "age_group"
    case amazonProductURL = "amazon_product_url"
    case articleChapterLink = "article_chapter_link"
    case author
    case bookImage = "book_image"
    case bookImageWidth = "book_image_width"
    case bookImageHeight = "book_image_height"
    case bookReviewLink = "book_review_link"
    case bookUri = "book_uri"
    case btrn
    case contributor
    case contributorNote = "contributor_note"
    case createdDate = "created_date"
    case description
    case firstChapterLink = "first_chapter_link"
    case price
    case primaryIsbn10 = "primary_isbn10"
    case primaryIsbn13 = "primary_isbn13"
    case publisher
    case rank
    case rankLastWeek = "rank_last_week"
    case sundayReviewLink = "sunday_review_link"
    case title
    case updatedDate = "updated_date"
    case weeksOnList = "weeks_on_list"
    case buyLinks = "buy_links"
  }

  init(ageGroup: String, amazonProductURL: URL, articleChapterLink: String, author: String, bookImage: URL?, bookImageWidth: Int?, bookImageHeight: Int?, bookReviewLink: String, bookUri: URL, btrn: String, contributor: String, contributorNote: String, createdDate: String, description: String, firstChapterLink: String, price: String, primaryIsbn10: String, primaryIsbn13: String, publisher: String, rank: Int, rankLastWeek: Int, sundayReviewLink: String, title: String, updatedDate: String, weeksOnList: Int, buyLinks: [BuyLink]) {
    self.ageGroup = ageGroup
    self.amazonProductURL = amazonProductURL
    self.articleChapterLink = articleChapterLink
    self.author = author
    self.bookImage = bookImage
    self.bookImageWidth = bookImageWidth
    self.bookImageHeight = bookImageHeight
    self.bookReviewLink = bookReviewLink
    self.bookUri = bookUri
    self.btrn = btrn
    self.contributor = contributor
    self.contributorNote = contributorNote
    self.createdDate = createdDate
    self.description = description
    self.firstChapterLink = firstChapterLink
    self.price = price
    self.primaryIsbn10 = primaryIsbn10
    self.primaryIsbn13 = primaryIsbn13
    self.publisher = publisher
    self.rank = rank
    self.rankLastWeek = rankLastWeek
    self.sundayReviewLink = sundayReviewLink
    self.title = title
    self.updatedDate = updatedDate
    self.weeksOnList = weeksOnList
    self.buyLinks = buyLinks
  }
}
'''


What is NYTTop100FictionModel here?

Is there only ever going to be exactly one instance of ListB in jsonData.results.listsb with listNameEncoded == "hardcover-fiction"?

@Sweeper yes there is only one list after the filter which contains multiple books

@sonle NYTTop100FictionModel is the top level struct from decoding the JSON which contains the lower level struct Result shown in the code above.

filter returns an array containing all the elements that matched the condition in the filter. If you are sure that there is exactly one element that will match the condition, use first(where:):
if let hardfictList = jsonData.results.listsb.first(where: { $0.listNameEncoded == "hardcover-fiction" }) {
    books = hardfictList.books
} else {
    // no ListB instances found that matches 'listNameEncoded == "hardcover-fiction"'
    // please handle this case appropriately. Perhaps:
    books = []
}


That works, thank you!
